# How to get reverse pairs of the list?

Tags: list, prolog, reverse

How can I reverse pairs of some list in Prolog?

For example:

```
?- reversePairs([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9], R).
R = [2,1,4,3,6,5,9,7].                     % expected answer
```

So far, I have written the following code:

```
reversePairs([X,Y|Xs], ReversedList) :-
   reversePairs([X,Y|Xs], [], ReversedList).

reversePairs([], ReversedList, ReversedList).
reversePairs([X,Y|Xs], Accum, ReversedList) :-
   reversePairs(Xs, [X,Y|Accum], ReversedList).
```

My code gives me the following answer:

```
?- reversePairs([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9], R).
R = [7,9,5,6,3,4,1,2].                     % observed answer
```

How can I correct my code to get the answer I want? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply :

```
reversePairs([],[]).

reversePairs([X,Y|T], [Y,X|RT]) :-
    reversePairs(T, RT).
```

This code fails if the number of elements is odd. What do you want to do for this case ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually, for my case last element can match with empty list, that means it is okey to stay alone @joel76

Comment: +0.5: How about adding a sample query `?- reverse_pairs([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9], R).` or maybe the query `?- reversePairs([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9], R).` and its output to your answer?

Comment: @repeat : at home, I wrote reverse_Pairs instead of reversePairs, then bad paste !!! I edit my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a funny possibility with [DCGs](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/dcg/):

```
reverp, [B,A] --> [A,B], !, reverp.
reverp --> [].

reversePairs(L1,L2) :- phrase(reverp,L1,L2).
```

It will also work on lists with odd number of elements.

Sample query:

```
?- reversePairs([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9], R).
R = [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 9, 7].

?- reversePairs([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], R).
R = [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 9].
```

Can be easily generalized to N elements:

```
revern(N), Lr --> { length(L,N) }, L, !, { reverse(L,Lr) }, revern(N).
revern(_) --> [].

reverseNuples(N,L1,L2) :- phrase(revern(N),L1,L2).
```

Sample query:

```
?- reverseNuples(3,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9],R).
R = [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 7, 9].
```

---

As [@repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4609915) mentions in a comment below, `reversePairs` is not symmetric: the query

```
?- reversePairs(L,[2,1,4,3,6,5]).
```

will loop forever. To fix that, we can use [`same_length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=same_length/2), to ensure that both terms are lists with same length:

```
reversePairs(L1,L2) :-
    same_length(L1,L2),
    phrase(reverp,L1,L2).
```

Comment: Why use `(!)/0` and not simply reverse the grammar rule order?

Comment: @repeat: without the cut it's nondeterministic and backtracks through the successive exchanges: `[1,2,3,4]; [2,1,3,4]; [2,1,4,3]`.

Comment: By the way, why did I get downvoted? is this answer wrong or not useful?

Comment: First, I liked the semicontext DCG "stunt"..., however `?- reversePairs([1,2,3,4,5,6],Xs).` succeeds with `Xs = [2,1,4,3,6,5]`, but `?- reversePairs(Xs,[2,1,4,3,6,5]).` loops. WTF?! The previous straight-forward answer by joel76 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34548307/4609915) handles both use-cases simply, elegantly, and correctly. That's why I voted your answer down: it answers a question not posed (about DCG details) while falling short on the actual question. Please do note that I would like to see some (other) cool uses of DCG semicontexts, so don't get too discouraged by my ramblings:)

Comment: This is one of the **extremely rare** cases, where a red cut is legitimate. But only, because all the problematic cases are hidden by non-termination. I hate it, nevertheless +1.

Comment: @repeat: sure. To fix that just add `same_length(L1,L2)` before `phrase(reverp,L1,L2)`. `same_length/2` is defined in `library(lists)` in SWI-Prolog, not sure about the other Prologs out there, but it's trivial to implement anyway. Anyway, my answer was just about showing a funny way to use DCGs to manipulate lists, not to get a downvote from you `:)`.

Comment: @repeat: I'm not trying to say that this is a good way of solving the problem or anything; the thing I like about it, though, is the way it can be very easily generalized to more than two terms, and that you don't care about the number of terms; I don't see an easy way to do that with a more standard way.

Comment: Fair enough. That s(X) was worked hard for, I admit;)